# React scroll library not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, frontend

I chose to use react-scroll to smooth scroll different sections from the menu bar. The problem is that when I onclick(using my phone) only moves for about 50px in the direction of section. When I onClick on firefox or another web browser it doesn't move at all. I've checked id of sections and its all good, even when I create a Link in App.js component the same behaviour occurs.

Is that a library bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Will you please add some code snippets?

Comment: Even the simplest command doesn't work as expected: <a onClick={() => scroll.scrollTo(300)}>Scroll To 100!</a>

Comment: @BillMetcalf There is really nothing to look at

Comment: dobra brajanku wal mi konia, sam to ogarnąłem essa @BillMetcalf